# UITableViewController Methods are not being called

Tags: iphone, uitableview

As the title says none of my tableview controller methods are being called.

The steps I went through to create my table view are as follows.

1) I created a new file based on UITableViewController and selected the create with xib option. I Named my file myStuffViewController.

2) I have a rootview controller which is a UIViewController. In this view I have a navigation controller that I want to push my tableview controller onto at a certain point.

3) I setup my tableview and nav controller like so

```
mystuff = [[MyStuffViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyStuffViewController"bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    accountView = [[AccountView alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];




    accountViewNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
     accountViewNavController.delegate = self;


    NSArray *ar= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:accountView,mystuff, nil];
    [accountViewNavController setViewControllers:ar animated:NO];
    [accountViewNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    accountView.title=@"Login";
```

4) Then when a user pushes a button I want to push the table view controller onto the stack like this.

```
[accountViewNavController pushViewController:mystuff animated:YES];
```

I've even tried calling [self.tableView reloadData] but none of the methods get called.

Could somebody propose why my table view methods are not being called?

**EDIT 1**

Just so I'm being as clear as I can be here is what my header file looks like. To be it doesnt seems like I'm missing anything.

```
@interface MyStuffViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> {
    RemixView *remixView;
    NSMutableArray *remixListArray;
    TBXML*tbxml;


}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *remixListArray;
@property(nonatomic,retain)RemixView *remixView;
@property(nonatomic ,retain)TBXML *tbxml;

-(void)fetchRemixList:(NSString *)uid key:(NSString *)k1;
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end
```

Comment: please check whether you have connected or coded for tableview delegate and data source

Comment: hmmmm, I'm sorry but I don't completely follow. I have coded for tableview delegate, the delegate methods were generated by xcode. From what I can see the view was automatically connected to the controller by xcode also. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I second you Narayanan. Just make sure that delegate has been set.

Comment: okay if you're totally satisfied that the delegate is pointing in the correct place then the next thing to check is the delegate method's signature - i.e.is it exactly as it should be? The easiest way to be absolutely sure the signature is correct is to copy it from the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check

1. You declare in the .h file that you implement the two table view delegates UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDatasource
2. In the NIB make sure you link to your delegate in file owner OR if you have created the TableView programmatically make sure you set the delegate ivar also.

Then see if the delegate methods start getting called

Comment: I believe I have done both of these things. I'm using a generated nib

Comment: In the nib - right click on the file's owner and check there is nothing clashing (shown in yellow); you can right click on the table also for another perspective on where all the IBOutlets and IBActions and delegates are pointing

Comment: the nibs source delegate and view are all pointing to the files owner. The files owner view datasource are all pointing to table view.... I've always had a pain using IB. I back out of this and try to just do it in code.

Comment: ok I've spotted something odd. In a sample nib file I found the tableview  has 2 referencing outlets, tableview and view. My table view only has one referencing outlet named view. There is no tableview one and I cant see how to add it in IB

Comment: right click the table itself. A grey box will appear with round buttons on the right. click and hold on the round button next to delegate - drag onto File's owner and then release from the drag - you should see a list of possible ivars which can be linked to the delegate - there should be one called tableView - select that one. It's not as complicated as I've made it sound btw.

Comment: I don't see an ivar called tableview in the file owner.... even though this was all generated by xcode. I dont know what the hell is going on. Feel a bout of rage coming on :/

Comment: Okay - I've just revisited a tableview of mine - in the nib when you right click you get a 'datasource' & 'delegate' which you need to link to File's owner. One last gotcha - check that File's owner is indeed the class which you have implemented the delegate methods in.

Comment: Youre going to hate me... I had number of sections set to 0. Thanks for all your efforts

Comment: I dont hate you - but would appreciate you selcting my answer IF that was the essence of the problem! Coongrats on sorting it out btw!